# Using glGetUniformIndices in PyOpenGL

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl

I have a uniform block like this:

```
layout(shared) uniform ProjectionMatrices {
  mat4 model_camera_xform;
  mat4 camera_clip_xform;
};
```

I would like to query the size and offset of the uniforms in this block. To do this, I first need to  get the indices of its members, using the `glGetUniformIndices` function, but I can't figure out how to use it.

Here is my attempt:

```
import ctypes as c
from OpenGL import GL
import numpy

name_array = c.c_char_p * len(uniform_names)
c_uniform_names = name_array(*[c.c_char_p(name.encode()) for name in uniform_names])
c_uniform_names = c.cast(c_uniform_names, c.POINTER(c.POINTER(c.c_char)))
uniform_indices = numpy.zeros(len(uniform_names), dtype='int32')
uniform_indices += 42
r = GL.glGetUniformIndices(program, len(uniform_names), c_uniform_names, uniform_indices)
err = GL.glGetError()
```

However, the result of this is that:

```
>>> print(uniform_names) # looks good.
['ProjectionMatrices.model_camera_xform', 'ProjectionMatrices.camera_clip_xform']
>>> print(err == GL.GL_NO_ERROR) # No error occurred
True
>>> print(r) # GL.GL_INVALID_INDEX, not sure what this refers to
4294967295
>>> print(uniform_indices) # Nothing has been set
[42 42]
```

Comment: Changing the `dtype` of `uniform_indices` to `'uint32'` helped, but the `uniform_names` also has to be changed (to exclude the block name). Will post an answer when I have worked this out completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve the problem of `uniform_indices` not being set, they had to be `uint32`, which can be done in a few ways:

```
uniform_indices = numpy.zeros(len(uniform_names), dtype='uint32')
uniform_indices = numpy.zeros(len(uniform_names), dtype=OpenGL.constants.GLuint)
uniform_indices = (OpenGL.constants.GLuint * len(uniform_names))()
```

After this, `uniform_indices` was set to `GL_INVALID_INDEX`. This was fixed by changing `uniform_names` to use the unqualified names:

```
uniform_names = ['model_camera_xform', 'camera_clip_xform']
```

The relevant section of the OpenGL 4.4 specification is **4.3.9 Interface Blocks**:

> Outside the shading language (i.e., in the API), members are similarly
>   identified except the block name is always used in place of the
>   instance name (API accesses are to shader interfaces, not to shaders).
>   If there is no instance name, then the API does not use the block name
>   to access a member, just the member name.